# How to load a keras model and restart the training from where it stopped

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am working on an LSTM based encoder-decoder model and it's not able to complete its training due to memory error. I asked about it in my previous question but didn't get any response.
[Memory error while training the keras model on 4600000 rows data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67804926/memory-error-while-training-the-keras-model-on-4600000-rows-data)

So to resolve the issue I came across the solution to reload the model where the training stopped and start the training again as follows.

```
train_samples = len(X_train)
val_samples = len(X_test)
batch_size = 128
epochs = 2

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

filepath = "model.h5"

keras_callbacks   = [
      EarlyStopping(monitor ="val_loss", mode ="min", patience = 5, restore_best_weights = True),
      ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
]

model.fit_generator(generator = generate_batch(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size),
                    #steps_per_epoch = train_samples//batch_size,
                    steps_per_epoch = 2000,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data = generate_batch(X_test, y_test, batch_size = batch_size),
                    validation_steps = val_samples//batch_size,
                    callbacks=keras_callbacks)

new_model = load_model(filepath)

# fit the model again
keras_callbacks   = [
      EarlyStopping(monitor ="val_loss", mode ="min", patience = 5, restore_best_weights = True),
      ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
]
new_model.fit_generator(generator = generate_batch(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size),
                    #steps_per_epoch = train_samples//batch_size,
                    steps_per_epoch = 2000,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data = generate_batch(X_test, y_test, batch_size = batch_size),
                    validation_steps = val_samples//batch_size,
                    callbacks=keras_callbacks)
```

Suppose if the training stopped after 2 epochs and I reload the model I got after 2 epochs and restart the training. But I see that there is no change in the val_accuracy or val_loss. It is exactly the same it was during the previous epochs.

Can someone suggest some other way to do so? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean no change on accuracy or loss?

Comment: @M.Innat on every epoch one would expect the accuracy to increase and loss to decrease but when I reload the model where the training stopped and restart the training, the metrics are still the same as that during the first run.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common need among AI practitioners and the solution is simple.
You have to save your model somewhere as a checkpoint.

These links will help you:
[Keras Model Chekpoints](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint)
[Loading a model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load)

So basically you have to save your model, and if you stop your programme after 2 epochs you can load the checkpoints. (based on the frequency that you save the model)

Comment: I did follow this process. Saved the model to a checkpoint after each epoch and loaded the saved model to restart the training but I don't see any change in the model. The val_loss, val_accuracy and other metrics don't change they are the same as they were in the previous epochs.